# Went from QGraphicsView to QMainWindow now keyPressEvent doesn't see arrow keys

Tags: python, event-handling, pyqt4, keyboard-shortcuts, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to learn about the event handling in PyQt4 and stumbled upon a case where
`keyPressEvent` sees all keys except the arrow keys after I changed the class definition.

From seeing all keys:

```
class MaskWindow(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)

        self.deskTop = QtGui.QDesktopWidget()
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
```

To can't see the arrow keys, page-down and up, but others work e.g. <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>:

```
class MaskWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|
                                   QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)            

        self.deskTop = QtGui.QDesktopWidget()
        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
```

Here's the key handler where the arrow key doesn't trap anymore:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    key = event.key()
    if key == QtCore.Qt.UpArrow
        self.diameter += 1
    if key == QtCore.Qt.DownArrow:
        self.diameter -= 1
```

What did I miss with the class change?

Comment: It's almost certainly because of the window flags that you are passing to the constructor. What platform are you on?

Comment: This was on windows 7.  I chose the QMainWindow so i could set window to top and lose the border.  Is there a way to do this with a QGraphicsView object instead?

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment, and see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Your reimplemented `keyPressEvent` function is using the wrong enumerated constants.

It should be using the [QtCore.Qt.Key](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qt.html#Key-enum) enumeration:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    key = event.key()
    if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
        self.diameter += 1
    if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
        self.diameter -= 1
```

And the window-flags can be changed on any widget (including `QGraphicsView`) by using the [`setWidowFlags`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) function:

```
class MaskWindow(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() |
            QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint |
            QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

**Update**

The reason why the reimplemented `keyPressEvent` doesn't work with the `QMainWindow` in your example is because it won't get any key events any more - they'll go to the child widget with the keyboard focus instead.

One way to work around that would be to set an [`event filter`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter) on the widget you want to get key events from:

```
class MaskWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None,
            QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint |
            QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)
        self.view.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (source is self.view and
            event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress):
            key = event.key()
            if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
                self.diameter += 1
            elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
                self.diameter -= 1
        return QtGui.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event)
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked using the GraphicsView window flags.  I still am not clear why the QMainWindow approach did not trap the arrow keys after I changed the QtCore.Qt.UpArrow to QtCore.Qt.Key_Up as you suggested.  This is more from a curiosity point of view.

Comment: @Dave. I've updated my answer with a more complete explanation.

Comment: Excellent,  I think i'm getting most of it except the return QtGui.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event) at the end.  What is the reason for that last line?

Comment: @Dave. Calling the base-class `eventFilter` ensures that the default event handling still works correctly. However, if you wanted to prevent any further handling for a *particular event*, you can just return `True` instead. See the [docs for eventFilter](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter) for more details.